# Flutter Android application not filling the screen

Tags: android, flutter

I've just started learning Flutter and I am debugging on my phone (Redmi Note11).

However, I notice the application won't fit my screen, leaving a blank space at the bottom. The blank space also appears on the splash screen.

[Splash Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9ODs.png)
[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnqDj.png)

I have tried putting `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` in my Scaffold widget, but it doesn't help. The tutorial that I'm following does not have this problem too.

Also would like to know any reason why is my splash screen so dim.

Thank you.

Comment: set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` to `false`

Comment: It's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

try this inside your Scaffold,
body:Center(
child: Image.asset("your_asset")
)